# Customize mail content for UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

I've been searching the web for hours regarding this, yet couldn't find a proper solution. Really annoying that a simple (and standard) task like that isn't properly documented by Apple...

Basically I'd like to customize the mail content when the user presses the share via mail button on an UIActivityViewController. I need to set the subject, HTML text and an image.

I know how to write a custom mail activity, but I'd rather use the default Mail share action presented in the activity controller's share section.

This is just the boiler plate default code I'm using right now;

```
BookmarkUIActivity *ba = [[BookmarkUIActivity alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray new];
[items addObject:@"this is just demo text"];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:ba, nil]];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[];
activityVC.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = self.actionButtonItem;

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:true completion:nil];
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! Note, it has to work with both iOS7 and iOS8.

Edit: For the record, I'm aware of the fact that you can set the mail's subject using SetValue:forKey:@"subject" on the UIActivityViewController, but given that is is undocumented I'm very much interested in an official way of customizing the entire mail.